# using inline js on azure logic app failed

Tags: regex, azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to match some string from an event trigger that takes the event from event grid and save the
"matched" value for later use in actions on the same app

I created an integration account and the account is connected to the logic app

anyway,any code that I tring to write on the js inline scrip cannot be saved
when i tried to save the logic app I got this error:

```
Workflow validation failed for the workflow ''. {"error":{"code":"InternalServerError","message":"Encountered internal server error. The tracking Id is 'XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXX'."}}
```

I have tried to change the integration account plan and change the js code according to some examples that i saw on a few websites ( for tests)

example :

```
var routeTableRegex = /\/routeTables\/(.*?)\/routes/g;

var routes = workflowContext.trigger.outputs.body;

return routes.match(routeTableRegex);
```

action: condition

```
{
  "type": "If",
  "expression": {
    "and": [
      {
        "not": {
          "equals": [
            "@body('Execute_JavaScript_Code')",
            "@null"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "actions":`
```

Comment: So if you remove the inline javascript step it all saves successfully, is that right?

Comment: Yes,  its saved  if i remove the inline js     anyway i can give up on the inline script if there are another way to match a string from event and save it to variable

Comment: Yeah, there is but at the end of the day, you’re taking the cheapest approach. I suspect you’re in the free tier for the integration account. Type in “Regex” into the operations and you’ll get a few. Value for money, the Advanced Data Operations is a good one. Alternatively, you can use Office Scripts to run a match but it’ll be pretty slow.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the **`design`** which worked for me:

[image]

**`Script:`**

```
var routeTableRegex = /\/routeTables\/(.*?)\/routes/g;
var routes = workflowContext.actions.Compose.outputs;
return routes.match(routeTableRegex);
```

**`Output`**:

[image]

I do agree with @Skin, you might be in cheapest tier of integration account, because of which you are not getting it.